VS Code C# Dev Kit NuGet Package Source Telerik
With the retirement of VS for Mac I am having some trouble running my .Net MAUI apps in VS Code Mac due to every time I go to run the application it generates this error like it is missing the configuration for Telerik's source, This works in VS as I can go to the package settings and add the source there with my username and password but VS Code has no visual for this and in my MAUI Csproj file I don't have any Telerik package references so not too sure why it needs to search the source:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204/NuGet.targets(169,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json. [/Users/mainuser/Desktop/TestMauiApp/TestMauiApp/TestMauiApp.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204/NuGet.targets(169,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/Users/mainuser/Desktop/TestMauiApp/TestMauiApp/TestMauiApp.csproj]

When I go to VS Code settings > Extensions > Nuget Gallery I have added the source json in the menu but I don't think this is correct:
{"name": "Telerik UI","url": "https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json","Username": "XXX","ClearTextPassword": "XXX"}

does anybody know how to solve this problem or where to store the source?
